# I followed the " Bootstrap Modal fires but not ASP Button Click event" on stack overflow and it don't seem to work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Bootstrap Modal fires but not ASP Button Click event - Updated question

I followed the tutorial from the "Bootstrap Modal fires but not ASP Button Click event" on stack overflow and I copy and paste the code into my asp.net core. and It not even loading up the modal at all.I tried  UseSubmitBehavior = "false" to stop postback and I still cant get it to work.

home.aspx

```
 <div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
                  <h3>Enter Comments Below:</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <h4>Comments</h4>                  
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>  
                    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>                   
              </div>
          </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
           $('input[name$="TestButton2"]').on("click", function () {

               $('#example').modal('toggle');
               return false;

           });
     </script>
```

The c# code from the answer.
home.aspx.cs

```
protected void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {

                     // do something then call modal
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Show", "<script> $('#example').modal('toggle');</script>");
                    }
```

modal to pop up and I did try  UseSubmitBehavior = "false" which worked well for other js function like alert. I still not getting the modal to pop up.

Answer (score 0):

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "modal", "$('#exampleModal').modal('show');", true); //show popup